# Comparing String.endsWith(..) with regex equivalent

Tags: java, regex, string, compare

We have an application wherein we need to filter certain type of files. We *thought* that the regex way would be faster than simple [`Strings.endsWith()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29) method. But to validate the assumption, we did a small benchmark test. Following is the working code we used:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test{

       private static Pattern pattern;
       private static Matcher matcher;   
       private static final String IMAGE_PATTERN = "([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|css|js))$)";

       private static String[] files = {"jpeg","jpg","png","gif","bmp","css","js"};

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {   

        pattern = Pattern.compile(IMAGE_PATTERN);

        //Input Strings
        String input = args[0];
        String[] inputArr = input.split(",");

        Integer iterations = 10000;
        Integer i = 0;

        Long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while(i < iterations){

            for (int j = 0; j < inputArr.length; j++) {
                validateReg(inputArr[j]);
            }   
            i++;
        }       
        System.out.println("Time taken using regex:"+(System.currentTimeMillis() - t1));

        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        i=0;
        while(i < iterations){

            for (int j = 0; j < inputArr.length; j++) {
                validateStr(inputArr[j]);
            }
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("Time taken using .endsWith :"+(System.currentTimeMillis() - t1));

    } 

      public static boolean validateReg(final String file){

          matcher = pattern.matcher(file);
          return matcher.matches();

       }

      public static boolean validateStr(final String file){

          for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

              if(file.endsWith(files[i])){
                  return true;
              }
        }
            return false;
       }      
 }
```

For the input `abc.jpg,efg.css,jij.jpeg,test.java,best.css,not.gif,f.exe,test.js,su.css,not.js,yes,png`

It prints :

```
Time taken using regex:89
Time taken using .endsWith :6
```

and the numbers are fairly same for multiple runs. Result is same even if the order the execution of while loop is changed. It appears that String.endsWith() is much faster that its regex equivalent.

Now **My question is:**,  is this benchmarking method correct to conclude this ? Or are there any better and more credible way to test this scenario ?

Comment: Why would you expect the regex approach to be faster? The `endsWith` method has one very specific job to do, whereas a regex is general purpose. Aside from anything else, if using a regex could implement `endsWith` as quickly as the hard-coded version, `endsWith` could have been *implemented* with `endsWith`...

Comment: Thanks Jon. I was under impression (wrong though) that the endsWith uses iterations iterations whereas  regex does it at lower level. It appears the opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String.endsWith` works by simply comparing bytes (chars) from the end of compared strings. Regexp, on the other hand, need much more time to parse regexp, compile it, build matcher and execute it. But as to your question: this test is roughly OK at least to show discrepancy between regexp and endsWith. In more precise measurement, you should pick start timestamps as late as possible, possibly excluding loop overhead and end timestamps as soon as possible, then perform some computing (summing periods). For instance:

```
long t0, t1, tt = 0L;
for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++) {
    t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //- Execute the code its execution time you want to measure here.
    t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    tt += (t1 - t0);
}
System.out.println("Total time: " + tt + "ms");
```

For more precise measurements you can use `System.nanoTime()`.

Comment: "comparing bytes (chars)" suggests that bytes and chars are the same thing, whereas they're very much not...

Comment: Does "comparing bricks (walls)" suggests that bricks and walls are the same thing?... What does original sentence suggest, is whether implementation compares bytes or chars, it works as described.

Answer (score 1):

I find `endsWith` being faster normal. I doubt any need much testing to conclude this.

Plain string searching methods are generally faster than regex (not just in Java).